# Angular 2-way binding not working but expression does

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in repo.items">
  <div class="col-md-6 segment">
    <div class="display-text animation editable">
      <pre><span class="contenteditable" 
          tabindex="0"
          contenteditable="true"
          ng-model="item.text"></span></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The 2-way binding isn't working for ng-model="item.text", but if I use the expression `{{item.text}}` within the same iteration it works as it should.

Any specific reason I'm missing which is causing this behavior?

Comment: post your full code including controller.

Comment: `ng-model` is only used for input tags and not span!! use `{{item.text}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-model` used for *input* tag when you want to use only for view you should use `ng-bind`.

So you should use `ng-bind="item.text"` or `{{item.text}}` instead of `ng-model="item.text"` in `span` tag.

```
<pre>
     <span class="contenteditable" 
          tabindex="0"
          contenteditable="true"
          ng-bind="item.text"></span>
</pre>
```

or

```
<pre>
     <span class="contenteditable" 
           tabindex="0"
           contenteditable="true">{{item.text}}</span>
</pre>
```